# How does a conditional expectation transform into a simple expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have random variables $X$ and $N$.

It is given

$E[X|N] = N + cE[X] + d$

Why is the above statement equivalent to

$E[X] = E[N] + cE[X] + d$

where $c$ and $d$ are just constants in real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\mathbb{E}_{X}[X\mid N] = N + c \cdot \mathbb{E}_{X}[X] + d$, 
$$\mathbb{E}_{X}[X] = \mathbb{E}_{N}\left[\mathbb{E}_{X}[X \mid N]\right] = \mathbb{E}_{N}\left[N + c \cdot \mathbb{E}_{X}[X] + d\right] = \mathbb{E}_{N}[N] + \underbrace{c\cdot \mathbb{E}_{X}[X]}_{\text{constant with respect to }N}+d\text{,}$$
by double expectation.

Comment: What is the meaning of $E_X$ and $E_N$ (rather than, say, $E$)?

Comment: I guess we shall never know...

Comment: @Did - The use of the subscript, e.g., $\mathbb{E}_{X}[X]$, is used to emphasize that the expectation is taken with respect to the random variable $X$. I find it helpful especially with double expectation and the law of total variance and their uses in actuarial exam questions.

Comment: @Did - Furthermore, technically speaking, it should be $\mathbb{E}_{X}[X] = \mathbb{E}_{N}\left[\mathbb{E}_{X \mid N}[X \mid N]\right]$, but I have seen it usually written as I have it in the answer.

Comment: Am I right in deducing from your explanations that every $E_X$, $E_N$ and $E_{X|N}$ (although you did not explain the meaning of this last one) could be replaced by $E$?

Comment: @Did - Yes, indeed they could be.

Comment: This seems to amount to replacing systematically $E(\text{something})$ by $E_{\text{something}}(\text{something})$. Then I see no use for the notation, sorry (and I would be at pain to give a meaning to "taking an expectation with respect to a random variable", if I had to).

Comment: @Did - Point taken. However, I find $\mathbb{E}[Y \mid \boldsymbol{x}] = \mathbb{E}_{\Theta \mid \boldsymbol{x}}\left[\mathbb{E}_{Y \mid \Theta}[Y \mid \Theta]\right]$ (for Bayesian expectation) useful.

Comment: Which seems just a confusing way to write $E(Y\mid x)=E(E(Y\mid \Theta,x)\mid x)$. Yes Bayesians do this all the time--but while they do, others watch them in disbelief and disgust... :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is called the [*tower property*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Iterated_expectation): for every random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $X$ is integrable, $$E(E(X\mid Y))=E(X).$$